# cumsum with multiple condition in three column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have data:

```
WeekNumber  Col2        Col3        Value1     Value2
1           Jonas       Station1    8          3
2           Greg        Station1    5          1
3           Anton       Station1    1          2
1           Jonas       Station1    4          6
2           Greg        Station1    4          7
3           Mick        Station2    8          3
4           Anton       Station3    7          2
1           Jonas       Station1    2          3
2           Greg        Station1    7          1
```

I tried:

> df.groupby(['Col2','Col3','WeekNumber'])['Value2','Value2'].cumsum()

But this solution don't calculate 'cumsum'.
How to calculate cumsum in Value1 and Value 2, growing in WeekNumber based on condition in: Col2 and Col3

I need like this:
| Tables        | Are           | Cool  |
| ------------- |:-------------:| -----:|
| col 3 is      | right-aligned | $1600 |
| col 2 is      | centered      |   $12 |
| zebra stripes | are neat      |    $1 |

Comment: @jezrael he wants to increment it by 1 if already present

Comment: Can you clarify how `Jonas       Station4` has been migrated to `Jonas       Station1` in the desired result set?

Comment: There should be Jonas Station1

Comment: @MaxU I corrected it.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC:

```
In [47]: x = df.groupby(['Col2','Col3','WeekNumber']) \
               .agg({'Value1':'cumsum', 'Value2':'cumsum','WeekNumber':'cumcount'})

In [48]: x['WeekNumber'] += df['WeekNumber']

In [49]: x
Out[49]:
   Value1  Value2  WeekNumber
0       8       3           1
1       5       1           2
2       1       2           3
3      12       9           2
4       9       8           3
5       8       3           3
6       7       2           4
7       2       3           1
8      16       9           4
```

Comment: I think OP is worried about WeekNumber it should increment over time by 1 keeping initial values

Comment: (I know it is unrelated but) 2 answers away from 3k!

Comment: Totally unrelated I agree

Comment: @Bharathshetty, i think OP  made a mistake with `Jonas       Station4`...

Comment: @Bharathshetty, [i've asked OP for a clarification...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46604339/cumsum-with-multiple-condition-in-three-column-pandas/46604560#comment80162142_46604339)

Comment: Your current solution is perfect.

Comment: This solution doesn't.

I dont have increment per week, based on Col1 and Col2.